# AngularJS view not reflecting $scope.model, though data is being set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, authentication, persistent-storage

Thank you so much for reading my question :)

Aim: I want to persist a logged-in user's name and photo if they open a new tab or refresh. When originally authenticating (calling `attempt.login` on the form submit), the view updates fine (like so:)

userController.js.coffee:

```
$scope.attemptLogin = ->
  $scope.showLoginForm = false
  $http.post(apiURL + "/login"
    email: $scope.credentials.email
    password: $scope.credentials.password
  ).success (data) ->
    if data.error
      console.log "error: " + data.error
    else
      $scope.user = data
      localStorageService.add("user", data)
```

The **problem** is that when I do a page load and try and set `$scope.user` from the local storage variable, (like so:) I see the `console.log $scope.user` just fine, but the view doesn't reflect any user data.

userController.js.coffee:

```
$timeout ->
  if localStorageService.get("user") == undefined
    $scope.user = {}
    $scope.loggedIn = false
    console.log "no user"
  else
    $scope.user = localStorageService.get("user")
    console.log $scope.user
    $scope.$digest()
, 1
```

As you can see I've tried to put it in a `$timeout` block to force the change to take place on the next digest, and even explicitly called `$scope.$digest()`. I don't know where I'm going wrong here, I've scrounged around the other SO's to no avail apparently. Any lucidity on the matter is greatly appreciated!

index.html:

```
<div class="login-signup" ng-cloak ng-controller="userController">
  <div class="user-details" id="user_details" ng-click="toggleUserMenu()" ng-show="loggedIn">
    <div>
      <img class="user-avatar-small" ng-model="user.photo_url" ng-src="{{user.photo_url}}">
      <div class="user-name" ng-model="user.name">
        {{user.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user-menu" ng-show="loggedIn && showUserMenu">
    <a href ng-click="logOut()"> Log Out</a>
  </div>
  <a href ng-click="toggleLoginForm()" ng-show="!loggedIn && !showLoginForm" ng-cloak>Log In</a>
  <form class="form-inline" name="loginForm" ng-show="showLoginForm" ng-submit="attemptLogin()"ng-cloak>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle login-form-glyph" ng-click="toggleLoginForm()"></span>
    <label class="sr-only" for="email">email address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ng-model="credentials.email" placeholder="email" class="form-control"/>
    <br/>
    <label class="sr-only" for="password">password</label>
    <input type ="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="password" class="form-control"/>
    <br/>
    <input class="form-control" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the change in `$scope.user` is not seen by the view. Try to wrap the `else` branch like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.user = data
    localStorageService.add("user", data)
})
```

This will force an update of the watches and a digest cycle. I'm not sure about your manual `digest` call, but you should probably avoid calling that.

Moreover, instead of using the low level `http`, you could rapresent your user as a `resource`User; in this way, Angular will return a promise and take care of automatically updating the view for you when the data is received.

[See also: resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

Comment: thank you for your answer. When I do the http call, the view updates fine. it's my initial check to see if there's a logged in user via localStorage that assigns the model data, but the view does not changes. And thank you for the tip about resource-based auth!

Answer (score 1):

In any strange situation with angularjs and updating view - always try:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.your_model = your_value;
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried this and wrapped `$scope.user =  localStorageService.get("user")` in a `$scope.apply ->` but unfortunately the view is still not displaying the user data.